# angularjs test verify that event is caught

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, tdd, karma-runner

I've recently started learning how to test in angular with karma/jasmine.

Here is the scenario:
I have a directive that listens to an event, and when called it calls a function on the directive scope.

Here is my test. The problem is that the function is never called. The below code does not work becuase spy cannot find the function that the listener calls. The directive function updates the listItems value. Not very TDD but currently it only works in reality, and not in the test :/

**directive**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app').directive('listComponent', function(utilities) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E', //element
            templateUrl: 'views/listComponent.html',
            scope: {
                listItems: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.title = attributes["title"];
                scope.listItemsGrouped = [];
                var primary = attributes["primaryField"];

                var itemsGrouped = _.groupBy( scope.listItems, function (obj) {
                    return obj[primary];
                });

                scope.listItems = [];
                angular.forEach(itemsGrouped[3016],function(item){
                    scope.listItems.push({dimValueParent: item.dimValueParent,dimValueChild: item.dimValueChild, value: item.value});
                });

                scope.$on('refreshListItems',
                    function(evt,affectedValues) {
                        scope.refreshList(affectedValues);
                    });

            },
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.refreshList = function(vals) {
                    //handle values affected by the update
                    angular.forEach(vals, function(affectedValue) {
                        var indexParent = utilities.findIndexOf($scope.listItems,"dimValueParent",affectedValue.Dimensions[0].Value);
                        var indexChild = utilities.findIndexOf($scope.listItems,"dimValueChild",affectedValue.Dimensions[1].Value);
                        if (indexParent > -1 && indexChild > -1) {
                            $scope.listItems[indexChild].value = affectedValue.CalculatedValue;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

**test code, before each**

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        localScope = $rootScope.$new();
        ele = angular.element(
            '<list-component title="Testing generic list" list-items="list" ></list-component>'
        );

        mockupDataFactory = konstruktMockupData.getInstance();

        //these variables are needed.
        scope.data = mockupDataFactory.pivotedData;

        scope.listItems = [
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "100", value:101},
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "110", value:102},
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "120", value:103}];

        scope.affectedValues = [
            {CalculatedValue: 1000,Dimensions:[{ Key: "1", Value: "3016" }, { Key: "4", Value: "100" }]},
            {CalculatedValue: 1100,Dimensions: [{ Key: "1", Value: "3016" }, { Key: "4", Value: "110" }]},
            {CalculatedValue: 1200,Dimensions: [{ Key: "1", Value: "3016" }, { Key: "4", Value: "120" }]}];

        scope.$apply();

    }));
```

**Here is the test that is failing**

```
 it('Should handle an update listItems event', inject(function (){
        var affectedAccountsAfterUpdateExpcted = [
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "100", value:1000},
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "110", value:1100},
            {dimValueParent: "3016",dimValueChild: "120", value:1200}];


        //spyOn(localScope, "refreshList");
        scope.$broadcast("refreshListItems", scope.affectedValues);

        spyOn(scope, "$on").andCallFake(function (event, affectedValues) {
            expect(affectedValues).toBe(scope.affectedValues);
            expect(event).toEqual("refreshListItems");
        });

        expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();

        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.listItems).toBeDefined();
        //expect(scope.listItems).toEqual(affectedAccountsAfterUpdateExpcted);
    }));
```

I am struggeling as to what to do next. this is an update based on lght's answer. How to fix so that the event is caught in the test?  It seems that spy on isn't beeing called. Strange since I'm broadcasting the event!?

Comment: Instead of trying to check if the event is catched, what i'm doing is checking if the scope is listening for a particular event by mocking `$on`

Comment: Ok, do you have an example?

Comment: Since you added a spy on `$on`, you shouldn't be broadcasting your event anymore. Otherwise, you should be spying on your directive's scope, not on the `$rootScope`

Comment: ok. I've now changed the scope to be $rootScope.new(). I'm broadcasting from the parent scope and spying on the local scope.             `scope.$parent.$broadcast("refreshListItems",scope.affectedValues);`
`spyOn(scope, "$on").andCallFake(function (event, affectedValues){});scope.$apply();``expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: I'm still getting an error saying "Expected spy $on to have been called"

Comment: I think it's more an issue about the way you get your `scope` than the spy. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371836/how-to-unit-test-isolated-scope-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to check if the event is catched, what i'm doing is checking if the scope is listening for a particular event by mocking `$on`

```
describe("Testing the initialization", function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    controller = $controller("connectionBannerCtrl", {
      $rootScope: $rootScope,
      $scope: $scope,
      ConnectionBanner: ConnectionBanner
    });
  });
  it("should subscribe to the 'ConnectionBannerChanged' event", function () {
    spyOn($rootScope, "$on").andCallFake(function (event, callback) {
      expect(callback).toBe($scope.setup);
      expect(event).toEqual("ConnectionBannerChanged");
    });
    controller = $controller("connectionBannerCtrl", {
      $rootScope: $rootScope,
      $scope: $scope,
      ConnectionBanner: ConnectionBanner
    });
    expect($rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

It's all about the `spyOn` (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Comment: I tried something like the above but with no luck... Please see my revised question. It seems that the Spy on isnt called

Answer (score 0):

Don't `spyOn`, all you need to do is `broadcast` the event and the rest should come through automagically.

```js
it('should call the event', () => {
  spyOn(scope, 'refreshList');
  scope.$broadcast('refreshListItems');
  expect(scope.refreshList).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```