# Testing an attribute of isolated scope from a directive

Tags: angularjs

I've already examined [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371836/how-to-unit-test-isolated-scope-directive-in-angularjs) Q&A related to directives isolated scopes which helped me to resolve testing an attribute that used the `'@'` property; but I'm finding it difficult to test attributes that make use of the `'='` property.

Consider (from my directive called upcoming):

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            upcoming: '@',
            patientDetails: '='
        }
     };
```

In my test for `upcoming` I can access it (from angular 1.2 onwards) using the `isolateScope()` function like so:

```
    elm = angular.element('<div upcoming="remembered" patient-details="patientDetails"></div>');

    // Compiles the directive and links it to the scope
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    isolateScope = elm.isolateScope();
```

And in the tests I can do this:

```
it("should have attribute 'upcoming' attached to isolate scope", function () {
    expect(isolateScope.upcoming).toBeDefined();
    expect(isolateScope.upcoming).toBe('remembered');
});
```

But if I approach the other property in the same way I get the `undefined` error. I then tried this:

```
 // Retrieve the target html - remembered.html
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile) {
    patient = {
        name: 'Lorem Ipsum',
        readyForRefill: 1,
        progressCount: 2,
        upcomingCount: 3,
        taggedCount: 4,
        expiringCount: 5,
        oneRefillRemaining: 9000
    };
    elm = angular.element('<div upcoming="remembered" patient-details="patient"></div>');

    // Compiles the directive and links it to the scope
    $compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    isolateScope = elm.isolateScope();
    isolateScope.patientDetails = patient;
}));
```

The test:

```
it("should have attribute 'patientDetails' attached to isolate scope", function () {
    expect(isolateScope.patientDetails).toBeDefined();
});
```

passes but I feel like this is testing the wrong thing.

Can anyone clarify this for me please?

**EDIT**

Doing what tasseKATT suggested solved the problem but did happen to break 5 other tests. These tests basically examined the actual template being loaded and determined what contents they had. For example:

```
it("ul should contain 4 li", function () {
    var li = elm.find('li');
    expect(li.length).toBe(4);
});
```

is no longer valid as the `elm` element is now the `<div upcoming="remembered" patient-details="patient"></div>` html as opposed to the one loaded via the template:

```
<p><a href=""><b>Sign in</b></a> to view your full <br>prescription statuses.</p>
<ul>
    <li><span>{{patientDetails.readyForRefill}}</span> Prescriptions Ready for Refill</li>
    <li><span>{{patientDetails.readyForRefill}}</span> ReadyFill<sup>&#174;</sup> 
    <li><span>{{patientDetails.expiringCount}}</span> Expiring Prescriptions</li>
    <li><span>{{patientDetails.oneRefillRemaining}}</span> Prescriptions with 1 Refill Left</li>
</ul>
```

Is there away to load both correctly? Though it is worth noting that depending on who logs in, the template will change so would that render any attempt to count divs and p tags irrelevant for the tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the scope of the directive gets passed the correct patient details object you should put it in the scope before the element is compiled. You can then retrieve it via `isolateScope()` and perform your validations.

For example:

```
elm = angular.element('<div upcoming="remembered" patient-details="patient"></div>');

scope = $rootScope.$new();

scope.patient = {
  name: 'Lorem Ipsum',
  readyForRefill: 1,
  progressCount: 2,
  upcomingCount: 3,
  taggedCount: 4,
  expiringCount: 5,
  oneRefillRemaining: 9000
};

$compile(elm)(scope);
isolateScope = elm.isolateScope();
```

And:

```
it("should work", function() {
  expect(isolateScope.patientDetails).toBeDefined();
  expect(isolateScope.patientDetails.name).toBe('Lorem Ipsum');
});
```

**Update:**

If you really need to test generated markup you should use the compiled element:

```
compiled = $compile(elm)(scope);

...

it("ul should contain 4 li", function () {
    var li = compiled.find('li');
    expect(li.length).toBe(4);
});
```

Comment: That did solve my issue but happened to break some of the other tests - see my edit as to what it does

Comment: I did what you said but the tests still fail based on the previous corrections made - to get round this I'll have to load it in the previous manner but create a different element to house it - good or bad?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole picture. My first answer uses the same element as you are in your question, so I don't really understand how it could break the other tests.