# Jasmine unit test for Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have the following angular directive, which adds a tooltip when I hover over a span.

```
angular.module('mainMod')
    .directive('toolTip', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                theTooltip: '@toolTip'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.tooltip({ 
                        delay: 0, 
                        showURL: false, 
                        bodyHandler: function() {
                            return jQuery('<div class="hover">').text(scope.theTooltip);
                        } 
                });
            }
        }
    }])
    ;


<span ng-show="data.tooltip" class="icon" tool-tip="{{data.tooltip}}"></span>
```

I'm looking to write a unit test for this directive, atm I can't use [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery).

I'm fairly new to writing unit tests, could anyone possibly help me out?

Give me some pointers or point me towards some helpful resources?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What I have atm isn't much...

```
describe('Unit testing tooltip', function() {
    var $compile;
    var $rootScope;

    // Load the myApp module, which contains the directive
    beforeEach(module('mainMod'));

    // Store references to $rootScope and $compile
    // so they are available to all tests in this describe block
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
      // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));


    it(' ', function() {
        // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive
        FAILS HERE --> var element = $compile("<span class='icon' tool-tip='{{data.tooltip}}'></span>")($rootScope); 

        $rootScope.$digest();

    });
});
```

It's failing with a message of

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I think it's being caused by the ($rootScope) at the end of the line I've specified above.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your DOM content with angular.element first before compiling it. I am not sure what the tooltip module you are using but I used the jQuery UI tooltip instead.

```
    //create a new scope with $rootScope if you want
    $scope  = $rootScope.$new();

    var element = angular.element("<span class='icon' tool-tip='This is the tooltip data'></span>");

    //use the current scope has just been created above for the directive
    $compile(element)($scope);
```

One more thing, because you are using isolate scope in your directive, to get the current scope from your directive, you need to call

```
   element.isolateScope()
```

based on this reference : [How to Unit Test Isolated Scope Directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371836/how-to-unit-test-isolated-scope-directive-in-angularjs)

For a working fiddle, you can found it here : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/4w52wsms/1/

Comment: According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile, you don't have to wrap anything, a string template is just fine. Also, there's no need to worry about getting the isolated scope when testing the unit from the outside.

Comment: Have you tried without using the angular.element, because when I remove that part, it will cause error. Maybe it relates to angular version.

Comment: I use `$compile` to compile string templates in all directive tests across a wide array of AngularJS versions without any problems.

Comment: Can you please update my fiddle with $compile without angular element ? It will be great :)

Comment: Wow, thanks alot. How about the isolate scope part, any ways to get the directive scope ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65340/discussion-between-hon2a-and-themyth92).

Answer (score -1):

Any unit test is basically the same - mock the environment, construct the unit, check that the unit interacts with the environment in the expected manner. In this instance, you'd probably want to mock the tooltip creator

```
spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'tooltip');
```

then compile some template using the directive (which you're already doing), then simulate the hover event on the compiled element and then check that the tooltip creator was called in the expected manner

```
expect(jQuery.fn.tooltip).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    // ... (expected properties)
}));
```

How you simulate the event depends on how the `element.tooltip` is supposed to work. If it really works the way you're using it in the question code, you don't need to simulate anything at all and just check the expected interaction right after template compilation.

Comment: Thanks a lot hon2a. It really does work how I've described it in the question. I think I have a decent understanding of what steps to take, but the test is failing on me in the line I've highlighted above, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Daft Then you need to do a little debugging and find out exactly, what is failing. From here, without knowing anything about `tooltip`, I can see just 3 possible things that might not exist - `.tooltip` plugin, `jQuery` function, and `.text` function. Find out, which one is it, and act accordingly.

Comment: @Daft On a sidenote, you really shouldn't use `jQuery('<div class="hover">')` to create an element. Either use `jQuery('<div>').addClass('hover')` (which creates element by tag name) or `jQuery('<div class="hover"></div>')` (proper HTML fragment).